# why breadcrumb has wrong orders?

Tags: breadcrumb

Here is my code:

```
function the_breadcrumb() {
if (!is_home()) {
    echo '<a href="';        echo get_option('home');        echo '">';
    bloginfo('name');
    echo "</a> / ";
    if (is_category() || is_single()) {
        the_category();
        if (is_single()) {
            echo " / ";
            the_title();
        }
    } elseif (is_page()) {
        echo the_title();
    }
}
}
```

It gives a wrong result:

```
website name > cat1 > cat1 sub1 > cat1 sub2 > cat1 sub3 > your location
```

The order I try to get:

```
home >cat1 > cart1 sub1 >your location
```

Can someone tell me what I have to change?

Comment: What categories is this post assigned to?

Comment: i use <?php the_breadcrumb(); ?> in a sub categories page.single-new.php. I have several single pages.

Comment: That is not answer to my question ;) You gave example of wrong breadcrumbs `website name > cat1 > cat1 sub1 > cat1 sub2 > cat1 sub3 > your location`. So what categories is this post assigned to? If post is assigned to many categories, then which one of them would you like to see n breadcrumbs?

Comment: a little bit confused. I assigned it to `cat1 sub2`

Comment: So it's assigned to only one category? It's a little bit strange - `the_category` returns 4 categories... Where are you calling this `the_breadcrumb` function? Outside the loop, I guess?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I put one post in more than one category, that's the reason i get wrong breadcrumb. Thank you very much.